# Using command substitution in sed

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a markdown file that consists of many different headings, I am writing a CI script that modifies one of the section with every push to the repo. My README.md is as follows,

README.md

```markdown
# Title
....some text...
## Heading 1
...some text...

## Heading 2 
...some text....

## Structure
<pre>
┬  
 ├ first-dir
     ┬  first-sub-dir

 ├ second-dir
     ┬  second-sub-dir-1
     ├  second-sub-dir-2
</pre>

## Heading 3 
...some text....
```

I wanted to modify the `Structure` section with the output of the command `tree -d -L 2 -n` using sed. I tried using

```bsh
var=$(tree -d -L 2 -n)
sed -i -E "s/## Structure\n<pre>\n(.|\n)*?<\/pre>/## Structure\n<pre>\n ${var} \n<\/pre>/g" README.md
```

but it was not working properly. I read about command substitution in `sed` but I wasn't able to understand it properly. Any help regarding this with `sed` or `awk` will be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
/^<\/pre>$/             {flag=0}
/^## Structure$/        {print; getline; print
                        system("tree -d -L 2 -n")
                        flag=1}
!flag' <<<$(<file) >file
```

`<<<$(<file) >file` - a kind of custom buffer (does not work in all shells). It is possible to replace with a temporary file: `file >tmp`

A more complex way, I cite just for example:

```
sed -i '/^## Structure/!b
N;h
:1;N
/<\/pre>$/!b1
s/.*\n//
x;p
s/.*/tree -d -L 2 -n/e
G' file
```

`/^## Structure/!b` - All lines that do not match the pattern are ignored by the script. And are displayed unchanged. As soon as a pattern is encountered, the following script starts running.
`N` - Append the next line of input into the pattern space(working buffer). As a result, we have - `## Structure\n<pre>`
`h` - Copy pattern space to hold space (spare buffer).
`:1` - Put a mark for the jump.
`N` - Append the next line. We get in the working buffer - `## Structure\n<pre>\n┬`  
`/<\/pre>$/!b1` - If the end of the line in the working buffer does not match the pattern, then we return to label `:1` and add each cycle the next line until line `</pre>` is added.
`s/.*\n//` - Then we delete everything in the working buffer except the last line `</pre>`.
`x` - We change the contents of the buffers among themselves so that the line appears in the working buffer - `## Structure\n<pre>`. And in the spare buffer there is a line - `</pre>`
`p` - Printing the contents of the working buffer `## Structure\n<pre>`
`s/.*/tree -d -L 2 -n/e` - We replace the contents of the buffer with the shell command and execute it.
`G` - Append the contents `</pre>` of the spare buffer  to the working one - append to the output shell command. The content is printed and the job returns to the beginning of the script. The next line after `</pre>` is read into the working buffer. And since there are no more lines in the file matching pattern `/^## Structure/!b`, the remaining lines are also displayed unchanged as first.

Comment: Hello, can you explain the `sed` expression that you have wrote?